# Unable to copy WD My Cloud data to local machine. Error: No such file or directory

Tags: ssh

I have WD My Cloud NAS drive version 2 and from the last few days I am facing issues to use this drive and access the data using LAN.
After every restart the drive works for the next 5 to 10 minutes after that it hangs.

My Cloud home page also hangs after a few minutes.

Sometimes able to access the folder. And whenever trying to copy it hangs the copy window.

Sometime when trying to copy some files then it hangs after a few file transfers.

After googling and talking with customer care I come to know that I can copy or recover data using SSH.

Now able to access all my files and folder using SSH in MAC terminal but throwing an error when trying to copy the folder from My Cloud to Desktop.

The terminal is at root@MyWorld(I have given the name 'MyWorld') PhotosVideos and trying to copy complete RoadTripSouth folder to the desktop

**Command:** root@MyWorld PhotosVideos # scp -r RoadTripSouth/* /Users/vinit/Desktop/

**Error Message:** /Users/vinit/Desktop/: No such file or directory

**Question:**

1. Is there any way to recover complete data with a single or less amount of command instead of copying files one by one.
2. If able to access files then the hard disk is working. Then where is the problem?
3. If the problem is with firmware then how to fix this?
4. Through SSH also I am not getting much lead. What is the best way to recover complete data?

I think WD intensely doing all this thing when customers Hard drive warranty expires by updating the drive with corrupted firmware/software.

I have more than 3TB of personal data like family photos/videos and a single copy that is there in the drive.

From last one week, day and night working on this to recover the data and still not getting any lead.

Anyone please help and big thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This is why you have backups. Beware that operating the device could cause more damage to your data. So in case you don't have up to date backups you should probably stop reading here and get professional help recovering your data.

---

If the device freezes after using it for a few minutes this might be caused by overheating. Try cooling it with a fan. Instead of copying the files using SSH which needs to start over every time it aborts I would try using [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) over SSH:

```
rsync -aPh root@MyWorld MyWorld.backup
```

Comment: Yes, @Martin...we need to do backup always...
This NAS drive I used for backup only. Now the backup drives itself not working.
This is not possible to do the backup of backup or spent lots of money to buy the expensive hard disk.
If the problem with software then WD must need to provide a solution instead of raising hand and updating the drive with curupted firmware.